# Kerbal space program number binding

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Basically i want to be able to press 2 (or any number or key) and have my all solar panels deploy instead of having to activate them all one by one with many annoying mouse click.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 19):

You can do this with Action Groups.

This youtube tutorial provides a good example of how to do exactly what you want:

In short, once you have the solar panels added to your ship:

1. Click on the "Action Groups" icon at the top of the screen. It's the blue button that looks like two gears.
2. Select "Custom1" or whichever number you would like the action to bind to.
3. Click on the solar panels you would like to extend/retract when the key is pressed.
4. Then select "Toggle Panels" (or "Extend Panels"/"Retract Panels", if you only want this action to work in one direction.)

Now when your ship is launched, you can use whichever number key you bound this action group to to toggle your solar panels.

Comment: Please add at least a summary of steps of how to do this without the video.  Without that, this answer becomes useless if the video ever disappears.

Comment: As of 0.90, in career mode, you must now unlock Basic and Custom Action Groups by upgrading your Vehicle Assembly Building / Spaceplane Hangar.